# Counting occurrences by factor and over time interval

Tags: r, count, group-by

I currently have a single data frame (data, nrow = 10248) that information of tagged animals from 7/1/2013 to 10/3/2013 including the date (date), identification tag (id), the assigned group where the animal was tagged and released (trip), and if they were detected (presence; 0 = no, 1 = yes). See below for an example:

```
> data
            date   id trip presence
26    2013-07-01 9360    1        1
27    2013-07-01 9361    1        1
28    2013-07-02 9362    1        0
29    2013-07-02 9363    1        0
30    2013-07-03 9364    1        1
2349  2013-07-03 9343    1        1
2350  2013-07-04 9344    1        0
2351  2013-07-04 9345    1        1
2352  2013-07-05 9346    1        1
2353  2013-07-05 9347    1        1
2354  2013-07-06 9360    1        1
7102  2013-07-06 9416    2        1
7103  2013-07-06 9417    2        1
7104  2013-07-07 9360    1        1
7105  2013-07-07 9419    2        1
7106  2013-07-07 9420    2        1
7107  2013-07-08 9360    1        1
11102 2013-07-08 9386    3        0
11103 2013-07-08 9387    3        0
11104 2013-07-09 9360    1        1
11105 2013-07-09 9343    1        1
11106 2013-07-09 9390    3        1
11107 2013-07-09 9391    3        1
```

Another important piece of information is that each "trip" group has a different start date. For example:

- All animals tagged on 7/1/2013 for "trip 1" were allowed to roam
  freely until 10/3/2013.
- All animals in "trip 2" were tagged on
  7/6/2013 and allowed to roam until 10/3/2013.
- All "trip" groups have different start dates but ultimately end on 10/3/2013.

My overall goal is to count how many animals were detected (unique id's with presence = 1) over a specified time interval (e.g. 5 days) by the factor "trip".

My desired output would be something like the following (the frequency values bear no relation to the above table example):

```
trip         interval   frequency
   1    07/01 - 07/05          5
   1    07/06 - 07/10          4
   1    07/11 - 07/15          4
   2    07/06 - 07/10          5
   2    07/11 - 07/15          4
   2    07/16 - 07/20          3
   3    07/08 - 07/12          6
   3    07/13 - 07/17          6
   3    07/18 - 07/22          5
```

*Notice the different start dates for the trips.

Would anyone have any recommendations such as utilizing the `xts` or `zoo` packages or creating separate data frames for each "trip"? Please let me know if you need anymore information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perhaps a start for you. There may be more elegant ways of doing this, though. I use the package `dplyr` in my answer and assume that your data.frame is called `dd`.

```
dd$date <- as.Date(dd$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

intrvl <- 5

require(dplyr)

result <- dd %.%
  group_by(trip) %.%
  mutate(interval = floor((as.numeric(date - min(date)))/intrvl)+1) %.%
  filter(presence == 1) %.%
  group_by(interval, add = TRUE) %.%
  summarize(startDate = min(date),
            endDate = as.Date(startDate + intrvl -1, origin = "1970-01-01"),
            frequency = n()) %.%
  select(-interval)
```

Based on your sample datam, the result would then be:

```
> result
#  trip  startDate    endDate frequency
#1    1 2013-07-01 2013-07-05         7
#2    1 2013-07-06 2013-07-10         5
#3    2 2013-07-06 2013-07-10         4
#4    3 2013-07-09 2013-07-13         2
```

Note that in this solution, I assume that the start date for each trip is the first date that appears in any `trip` group (whether presenece is 1 or 0 is not taken into account, but could be easily adjusted if required).

Also note, that only those time intervals will be shown for each `trip` group, where the frequency of occurence is >=1.

Last but not least, you can easily vary the time interval by changing the variable `intrvl` to any other number.

Edit after comment by OP:

The following line

```
mutate(interval = floor((as.numeric(date - min(date)))/intrvl)+1) %.%
```

first creates a new column `interval` and then calculates the difference between the mininmum date per `trip` group (for example 2013-07-01 for the first group) and the date entry in the current row, this is converted to numeric. For example, if the difference is 3, then 3 is divided by the intrvl (5), which makes 3/5 which is between 0 and 1. Then, the `floor` function rounds this number down to the next integer smaller than the current value, so it is 0. Finally you add 1 and that is your interval group for that row (the first interval group runs in you example from 2013-07-01 until 2013-07-05). You can check this out by removing the last `%.% select(-interval)` from the code.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I have not experimented enough with `dplyr` but it seems very straight forward. Could you further explain what is occurring in the line `mutate(interval = floor((as.numeric(date - min(date)))/intrvl)+1) %.%`?

Comment: @ccapizzano I have added an explanation for that line.

Comment: Excellent, I was able to configure some of the code to output the number of unique transmitters per interval too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

With aggregate, using `cut.Date` to create the buckets:

```
aggregate(presence ~ trip + cut(as.Date(date), breaks='5 day'), data=data, FUN=sum)
##   trip cut(as.Date(date), breaks = "5 day") presence
## 1    1                           2013-07-01        7
## 2    1                           2013-07-06        5
## 3    2                           2013-07-06        4
## 4    3                           2013-07-06        2
```

This isn't quite what is wanted, as the start date for trip 3 should be 2013-07-08.  Splitting the data frame up by `trip`, performing the same computation (but no need to aggregate on `trip`) and recombining gives:

```
(d <- do.call(rbind,
    by(data, data$trip, 
       FUN=function(x) aggregate(presence ~ cut(as.Date(date), breaks='5 day'),
                                 data=x, FUN=sum)
    )
))
##     cut(as.Date(date), breaks = "5 day") presence
## 1.1                           2013-07-01        7
## 1.2                           2013-07-06        5
## 2                             2013-07-06        4
## 3                             2013-07-08        2
```

Here the row names indicate the trip:

```
d$trip <- gsub('[.].*$', '', rownames(d))
d
##     cut(as.Date(date), breaks = "5 day") presence trip
## 1.1                           2013-07-01        7    1
## 1.2                           2013-07-06        5    1
## 2                             2013-07-06        4    2
## 3                             2013-07-08        2    3
```

Comment: This solution is nice because it is very compact. I only wonder why the date for trip 3 is 2013-07-06. As I understood the OP, the time intervals (for example 5 days) are independent of the "starting date" per group.

Comment: Good catch, @beginneR.  This can be accomplished by treating each value of `trip` as a separate data frame.

Comment: +1 for the update (and still a very compact solution)

Comment: Thank you for an alternate solution using `base` code, much appreciated. I will give it a try shortly!